# Difference between these two queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

Below are two queries (WHERE query and JOIN query). The two queries have the potential to return two different result sets.

Which query might return more rows?
What subset of data must exist in order to have the queries return a different number of rows?

WHERE query:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.uid), r.name
FROM role r
LEFT JOIN users_roles ur ON r.rid = ur.rid
LEFT JOIN users u ON ur.uid = u.uid
WHERE u.status <> 0
GROUP BY r.rid
```

JOIN query:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.uid), r.name
FROM role r
LEFT JOIN users_roles ur ON r.rid = ur.rid
LEFT JOIN users u ON ur.uid = u.uid AND u.status <> 0
GROUP BY r.rid
```

what is the main reason for returning diff results and whats the difference between these two queries?

Answer (score 4):

The logic for a `left outer join` is the following.  Compare all rows in the first table to all rows in the second table.  If any pairs match the `on` condition, then keep them.  If no rows match a particular row in the first table, *then keep the row in the first table* and make all the other columns `NULL`.

This logic applies in all cases.  So, if you do:

```
select a.*
from a left join
     b
     on 1 = 0;
```

Then it will keep all rows in `a`, even though the `on` clause always evaluates to false. The filter has no effect, in a sense.

The same thing is happening in your query.  When you have

```
ON ur.uid = u.uid AND u.status <> 0
```

It is saying to keep all the rows in the preceding tables.  If there is a match with a non-zero status, then use that value for `u.status`.  Otherwise, the value is `NULL`.

When you have instead:

```
WHERE u.status <> 0
```

Then you are *really* saying:  the left join doesn't succeed and status <> 0.  The "safer" way to write this is:

```
WHERE u.status <> 0 or u.status IS NULL
```

However, it is clearer to put the condition in the `on` clause, because it really is part of the `left outer join`.

Comment: Thank you very much it makes sense to me now how it works. Thanks for the help, really appreciate.

Comment: @user3826912 Please accept the answer that helped you most. Accepting an answer will remove this question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3):

The WHERE query checks for `u.status <> 0` AFTER the join.
The JOIN query checks for `u.status <> 0` as part of the join.

So WHERE query will not return anything if `u.status = 0` whereas the JOIN query will, but will set all the fields from `users` to NULL.

By the way, `COUNT(u.uid)` is going to count the total number of non-null `uid`s are returned, not how many distinct `uid`s there are.

Comment: +1 In other words: the WHERE clause changes the OUTER JOINS to `INNER JOIN`.